# Sync framework filtering WCF NTier application

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I have developed sync application using the samples 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208

Also i have implement static  filtering  using
http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning/

But filter does not work as expected.

When i check the configurations in Client database which initiate sync has sync fiter configurations. but other end database (server) does not have any filter information.

Seems like Get Description of scope  doesn't include filters information. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetDescriptionForScope doesn't return the filter.

If you have the code you used to provision the scope with a filter, use the same code to provision the other database.

Comment: Thanks June. So basically i need to provision the other database using same way i provision local database. SO conclusion is it is not possible to use Get Description of scope from the server scope if you are using filter

Comment: I am thinking of using dynamic filter. If i used dynamic filter will it make difference

Comment: Sync fx doesn't support dynamic filtering. All filters, either standard or based on templates, are static filters

Comment: enable Sync Framework tracing to find out what's going on whether its not selecting changes or its encountering issues applying changes.

Comment: thanks i figure out the issue. i was passing parameter value  with quate for example 'Melbourne'.